# jQuery tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Why was the [jquery-ajax](/questions/tagged/jquery-ajax) tag made to be a synonym of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)? Especially, since the tag was used for questions, which had a particular relation to an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)/[XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) implementation other than using `$.ajax()`.

Shouldn't we also make [asp.net-ajax](/questions/tagged/asp.net-ajax) to be a synonym of [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) then?

Comment: What's wrong with said questions instead using [tag:jQuery] and [tag:Ajax]? Why does jQuery's shorthand of it need it's own tag?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I agree with this practice.  We created android-specific tags for specific objects like `activity` and `intent`.  We even synonymized `activity` and `intent` to `android-activity` and `android-intent`, because the Android folks were making a mess of things, and `activity` and `intent` can mean almost anything.  Some tags go all the way down to the method level.

Comment: @DarrenCook Then you can use jquery and ajax tags instead. Without this synonym, there are two different ways of tagging a question for the same thing, meaning if you want to find all questions that are about jquery's ajax you would have to search both jquery-ajax and jquery ajax. Now you can just search jquery ajax.

Comment: @DarrenCook That's more of an issue with email subscriptions then, not allowing you to specify a combination of tags. We shouldn't use tags just to "fix" email subscriptions.

Comment: @Stijn Thanks for the idea. My reply got too long, so I made an answer, and summarized my earlier comments there too.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree.

AJAX is part of the core of jQuery, so the synonym makes sense.

For ASP.NET however, it's a [separate package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_AJAX) to provide additional functionality.

Comment: @Stijin I agree that Ajax is the part of jquery but it is different, So I am disagree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Bring back `jquery-ajax`, please.

The goal of tags is allowing people to find questions they can answer, and thus allow askers to attract those people. The finer the tag scheme is the better, just until it becomes too fine, such that it is spread so thin that there would only be a handful of questions per tag (If you disagree with that one then we remove all tags and replace them with a single one called "stuff").

jQuery-AJAX was found to be useful by 19,000+ questioners. Obviously it's not too fine a distinction, and 19,000 people consider that their question was specifically about AJAX in the context of jQuery, and not about jQuery generally or AJAX generally (Though they may have added those tags too).

I'd propose that any tag that has less than N questions within a year of being created are removed, where N = 10 seems fine to me, but maybe N = 100 to people who think there are currently too many tags. Any tags that do not meet this criteria should not be touched.

As an example of why specific tags are good, I subscribe to the "SSE" tag, but I don't subscribe to the "HTML5" tag, because it will give me lots of noise, lots of questions I have no interest in, and won't be able to answer. I might subscribe to the "jQuery-AJAX" tag because I use it daily and might be able to help people. I won't subscribe to the "jQuery" tag because I don't want to get dozens of new questions each day that are about selectors, how to write your own plugin, requests for leads on existing plugins, and all the other stuff that goes on in jQuery that is not about AJAX. I also don't want to subscribe to AJAX, because I don't want the noise of people asking AJAX questions that are about using back-end languages for AJAX, or using other Javascript libraries for AJAX.

(Stijn suggested in the comments that people could subscribe/follow tag combinations. So I could say I only want to see questions tagged with "jQuery" that are also tagged "AJAX". That works for me too! Though it sounds more work for the Stack Exchange developers, and the UI will need some careful design).

(I'm not sure about policy regarding answers on meta, but this got too long to be a comment, sorry).