# Why does jquery-ajax tag disappear?

Tags: support, tags

I just edited one of my questions ( [Do JQuery.ajax call immediately, but not call callbacks until document.ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20539877/841830) ) to add the jquery-deferred tag; it previously had "jquery" and "jquery-ajax". I noticed this had the effect of removing the jquery-ajax tag! I tried re-editing a few times, but it won't come back. I added the "deferred" tag to prove to myself that three tags are allowed.

I also tried with just "deferred" and without "jquery-deferred", in case there was a rule that only one jquery-* tag allowed, but still jquery-ajax got removed.

The tag exists fine: I can see it, select it, and it is still there at the point I hit the "Save Edits" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jquery-ajax](/questions/tagged/jquery-ajax) [is a synonym of](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/synonyms) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). The synonym is being applied, and the resulting [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) is immediately ignored since that would put [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) on the post twice.

See also [a confused query about why this synonym exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219931/jquery-tag-synonyms).

Comment: Thanks, I just responded there. BTW, I tried deleting "jquery" and adding "jquery-ajax", but again it turns into "jquery". So it isn't about jquery not being allowed twice, it is that jquery-ajax is simply not allowed to be chosen any more.

Comment: @DarrenCook I think you may have misunderstood michaelb958's answer.  What he's saying is that "jquery jquery-ajax" is being transformed into "jquery jquery" because of the synonym, and then that's transformed into "jquery" because you can't have the same tag multiple times on one question.

Comment: @DarrenCook That's the intended interpretation, yes.